# JavaFX: Working with elements within another class

Tags: java, javafx-8

So the generally Idea I have is having a basic JavaFX app. So I make a new project and it has the default stuff such as

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception 
{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

and it has the basic button that when you click it prints hello world. So so far all i am trying to do is show you it is a basic default project.

now lets assume I have another class. Lets say that class runs on another thread and that when I type in a name into the console (in my case NetBeans) then it will update the button to say something else.

This is very general, I been googling and trying things with no perfect result. In hindsight, I am trying to make it so, I can have other classes edit the FXML document or elements on the page, then it will show on my program. I am not sure if I have to reload the FXML doc or reload the stage or what. I just wnat a guide or help on how to reference and change stuff around on a JavaFX FXML program. I been working on a chat program and been using normal Javafx with NO FXML and run into problems. So I am thinking about doing it on FXML. but I have times where I a class handle the user names and a class handle the messages for everyone to read and I need these classes to be able to edit the FXML document and reload it to show up. SO, if i user connects to the server, for example, the ListView object will now show that person name. like I said before, I have been able to do this working with Javafx without an FXML file, but my code is like spaghetti. Thanks in advance